# How to process data from CSV File and put that data in the room database and show it in recylerview?

Tags: android, sqlite, csv, android-studio, android-room

Check the repo  https://github.com/vivekpanchal/BabyApp

I am reading data and updating the adapter like this

The CSV file is inside the repo in Raw folder

want help in processing the CSV data

```
private void readData() {
    InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.babynames);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8"))
    );
    String line = "";

    try {
        reader.readLine();
        String mGender,mMeaning,mName,mOrigin;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            Log.d("MyActivity", "Line: " + line);

            String[] tokens = line.split(",");

            mGender=tokens[1];
            mMeaning=tokens[2];
            mName=tokens[3];
            mOrigin=tokens[4];


            BabyName babyName=new BabyName(mGender,mMeaning,mName,mOrigin);
            babyName.setGender(mGender);
            babyName.setName(mName);
            babyName.setOrigin(mOrigin);
            babyName.setMeaning(mMeaning);
            database.babyDao().insert(babyName);
            babyNames.add(babyName);
            Log.d(TAG, "Just created: " + mGender+mMeaning+mName+mOrigin);

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.wtf("MyActivity", "Error reading data file on line" + line, e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I gone through your GitHub project link, your CSV file has more than **22K** entries.
Other thing is you are **not reading data from Room**, you have just inserted those objects and updating adapter with ArrayList.

First of all you should **not** perform this **CPU Intensive** operation on main thread, This is **blocking UI** for long time. [Just tested code on my device]

Use worker thread or any other threading mechanism like **RxJava** to perform this **CPU Intensive** operation. Then return result to **Main Thread** and update your UI.

Taking this further, considering 22K entries you should consider using **pagination** provided with Android architecture libraries

Perform `private void readData()` operation on another thread, Create List of your objects and insert to database all at once. using another dao method like below

```
@Insert
void insertAll(List<BabyName> babyNames);
```

Observe `List<BabyName>` in Activity using `database.babyDao().getAllData();` method and in that observer set BabyNames to adapter as `adapter.setBabyNames(names)` and call `adapter.notifyDatasetChanged()`

This is how you can observe LiveData - example [ProductFragment](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/BasicSample/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/persistence/ui/ProductFragment.java)

```
// Observe product data
model.getObservableProduct().observe(this, new Observer<ProductEntity>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(@Nullable ProductEntity productEntity) {
        model.setProduct(productEntity);
       // Update adapter data and notify dataset changed here
    }
});
```

If you want to follow **Android Architecture Guidelines** considering you are using **Room** Database, go with MVVM architecture. You will start task for CSV Processing once the app is open and UI will observe for database changes using `LiveData`. So when your csv processing is completed and Database is updated you can view all those in your UI

Refer this for Pagination support - [Android Pagination](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/)

**Edit 1**

I have create [Pull Request](https://github.com/vivekpanchal/BabyApp/pull/2) on **GitHub** which fixes this problem.
Now app is running as expected.

**It fixes following issues**

- **CSV Processing** In Background
- BabyDao with required **LiveData** Methods
- MainActivity with Observing Baby List
- MainActivity processing CSV in background if already not inserted
- RecyclerView working properly - **LayoutManager bug fixed**

Comment: can you help me with this how to read data nd update the ui ? should i call loaddata() in adapter ? suggestion please how to do that.

Comment: Updated answer with steps you can take to insert data and observe it using LiveData in Activity

Comment: hey can you give a PR to that repository. i am new with these architecture patterns so getting confused .

Comment: Okay, Will try to add those steps which should make it work

Comment: That would be a really great help sir , i have created a issue you can just give a pull request to that

Comment: @vivekpanchal created PR over here https://github.com/vivekpanchal/BabyApp/pull/2

Comment: thanks sir will have a look in a bit thanks a lot sir

Comment: getting this error  incompatible types: LiveData<List<BabyName>> cannot be converted to List<BabyName>  in onBindViewMethod of Adapter

Comment: Its working on my side. You updated your local repository correctly ? Just clone the repo in new folder and try again https://github.com/vivekpanchal/BabyApp.git

Comment: Bro your code works but there are some errors I only need to display the Names in the recycled view but it's showing all the data.

Comment: You need to review your csv reader logic. I haven't changed anything in that logic. Its beyond scope of this question

Comment: Can you have a look at that? am I doing that right?  please sir  because i am getting the data of whole line in the recycler view

Comment: That is whole another question. But will look into that. You should consider accepting and upvoting this answer :)

Comment: Done sir anyway I can connect with you?

Comment: Added csv instructions here https://github.com/vivekpanchal/BabyApp/issues/3#issue-342336097