# How to import and manage conflicts an excel file into room sqlite database?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-room

I want to import an excel file into my database designed with room library on android.
I can export the database using a library but for import i need to check items and handle conflicts but I don't know how.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice to look on the following articles. [Article1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51396910/how-to-process-data-from-csv-file-and-put-that-data-in-the-room-database-and-sho) and [article2](https://mobikul.com/room-database-export-import-to-csv/) focuses on using room to import csv using room.

If you can use a different library, [this](https://parallelcodes.com/android-import-excel-into-sqlite-database-part-2/) is also helpful.

I will advise to break this functionality into two tasks.

1. Extract data from CSV/Excel file
2. Put that data into the database

**1 To extract data from CSV/Excel File, you can use the following code.**

```
    CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + TableName));
String[] nextLine;
int count = 0;
StringBuilder columns = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder value = new StringBuilder();
 
while ((nextLine = csvReader.readNext()) != null) {
      // nextLine[] is an array of values from the line
         for (int i = 0; i < nextLine.length - 1; i++) {
             if (count == 0) {
                 if (i == nextLine.length - 2)
                     columns.append(nextLine[i]);
                 else
                     columns.append(nextLine[i]).append(",");
             } else {
                 if (i == nextLine.length - 2)
                    value.append("'").append(nextLine[i]).append("'");
                 else
                    value.append("'").append(nextLine[i]).append("',");
             }
        }
```

2. To put the extracted data into the database you can use the following code.

Create a raw query function in your DAO.

```
@RawQuery  
Boolean insertDataRawFormat(SupportSQLiteQuery query);
```

Using that query put the data into the Database

```
SimpleSQLiteQuery query = new SimpleSQLiteQuery("Insert INTO " + tableName + " (" + columns + ") " + "values(" + value + ")",
           new Object[]{});
    getDb().cashDrawerDao().insertDataRawFormat(query);
```